# using AD620 with load cell

Tags: sensor, amplifier, output, instrumentation-amplifier, 5v

I am currently using an AD620 to amplify the signal coming from my load cell. I am supplying it with single supply of 5V and 0V. Below is my preliminary circuit.[image]

I am feeding half the supply to the reference pin so i am getting an output of 2.5V to 3.7V. I also tried feeding the reference pin of 1.5V and I am getting an output of 1.5V to 3.7V as expected from the information provided from the datasheet. What can i do to have a 0 to 5V rail-to-rail swing? Do i have to feed this output to a rail-to-rail op amp like an AD822?

************************************UPDATE*****************************************
[image]

I have modified it by using an AD822 "rail-to-rail" op amp to subtract a voltage so I could scale down my output from the AD620. is there something wrong with this? Because I am having some inaccuracies regarding my AD822 output.

Comment: Note that the 741 op-amp will not work with a supply as low as 5V. You'll need to use a different op-amp chip, one that is specified to work at 5V.

Comment: as of now, I replaced that 741 with a simple voltage divider with a pair of resistors to have a voltage reference to my AD620. but as expected it is unstable, what would you recommend to have a voltage ref of about 1.5V?

Comment: For a voltage reference (as opposed to the virtual ground shown in your schematic) I'd suggest the TL431. It's an adjustable band-gap reference diode, very commonly used and very cheap.

Comment: ok thanks @JohnHonniball I will try that one. i am thinking on using it to have a stable excitation voltage of 5V to my load cell and 5V reference voltage for my ADC. and also for the 1.5V reference voltage for the amplifier. is that part suitable for this purposes?

Comment: You'll need two TL431s if you want both a 5V reference and a 1.5V reference. But thinking about it, I don't think the TL431 can go below 2.5V. So, OK for the 5V but no good for 1.5V.

Comment: yes you're right. i have read the datasheet and it says that the minimun REF must be 2.5V so i can't use it for the 1.5V reference that i need. i have seen TLV431 which can have a lower output than the TL431, think i will check on that. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. What you need is a difference amplifier with gain. You can do this in a single stage, but I think you're better off doing it in two stages. First, create a voltage of 1.5 volts, and subtract that from your AD620 output. You can do that with a simple difference amplifier: one op amp and 4 equal resistors. You will now have a useable voltage swing of 0 to 2.2 volts. Then you make a non-inverting amplifier with a gain of a little more than 2, and boost your 0 to 2.2 to a 0 to 5 volt signal.

Comment: so i have to set my AD620 reference pin to 1.5V. i think i will research on this. thanks!

Comment: No, use the existing 2.5 volts. You say you're getting a minimum output of 1.5. If you subtract 1.5 from this, you'll get a minimum output of 0, which I presume is what you want.

Comment: I use the 1.5V reference to have a minimum output of 1.5 and also tested the 2.5V reference and have a minimum output of 2.5. But i also get voltages a little lower than my reference. Is that a problem? Does setting my reference voltage to 1.5V MUST mean that my output should start at 1.5V?

Comment: No. What I mean is, with whatever reference you use, you must measure the AD620 output at zero load, then subtract a little less than that from the AD620 output to get a zero load output slightly more than zero volts. And the reference must be such that the AD620 output is not pegged at whatever the minimum is with zero load on the cell. This is possible if you set your reference too low. Of course, the higher the reference, the less span you have to work with before the output becomes too high for the AD620 to drive it. And don't go too close to either extreme, either.

Comment: I have made the circuit and set the AD620 REF pin to 1.5V. Would it be right if I also use that ref voltage as the one to subtract to my AD620 output(tied to the inverting pin of the differential amp)? Because thats what I have done to my circuit, and then after I subtracted it, i amplified it using a non-inverting amp and now i get something like 10mV at zero load, which i think is ok.

Comment: That's probably fine. However, be aware that "rail to rail" op amps aren't really, and 10 mV may be the op amp. It's possible that the op amp is trying to drive 0 mv, but can't quite do it. Try monitoring the output as you load 1 kg, 2 kg and 3 kg loads. If the output does not change by exactly the same amount for each, and especially if the change for the 1 kg load is less than the change from 1 kg to 2 kg, put a little offset on your second op amp to increase the no-load output a bit, and repeat the test.

Comment: ok thanks! i think you're right that the 10mv is the minimum output of the op amp. i am now using a reference of 2.5V and having an output of 2.35V at zero load on my AD620. then i am subtracting 2.2V but i have a little problem because instead of having an output of 100mV+(2.35V - 2.22V), my output is on 80-90mV only. what could be the case? would you recommend having a wider range of output(lowering the reference)?

Comment: Your math is wrong, and your error is ~60 mV. This represents an error of ~3% in your difference amplifier. What precision resistors are you using? Even 1% units can give as much as 45 mV if you're unlucky, and it gets worse if you're using anything with lower tolerances. Plus, what is the offset of the op amp you're using? And where are you measuring your voltage? Difference amp or gain amp? The gain amp will amplify any errors from the diff amp. 45 mV from the diff amp, times ~2 from the gain amp will give 90 mV.

Comment: i only use simple resistors, but i can buy precision resistors if needed. I have updated my post with a new circuit. is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: First, the output voltage you show on the updated schemnatic is not what you've said. At zero load, is it 90 mV or is it 2.35 as you show? Now the last thing you need is a non-inverting amplifier with a gain adequate to bring your AD812 output up to the full scale swing you want. Fortunately, you have half an AD812 to work with. Third, replace your 4 1k resistors with 10k. Finally, when you say "simple resistors" I assume you mean 5% units. That's OK as long as you understand that this will give a different offset for each particular set of resistors. 1% will make your life easier.

Comment: it is 2.35V at the AD620, but once I have subtracted the 2.22V to it, I get 80-90mV at my AD822 diff amp which I think is an offset error because 2.35V - 2.22V must be something like 130mV right? yes i will use the other half to make a non-inverting amp. think i will replace the resistors with precision ones like you have said.

Comment: No, it's not an offset error, at least not in the sense of an op amp input offset. It's caused by the fact that the resistors are not exactly equal. Like I say, even 1% resistors can give up to 45 mV error. Look, you don't HAVE to use precision resistors. Put a 5k pot between the 20k and the 16k resistors, then take the wiper of the pot to the 324. This will allow you to vary the offset voltage to compensate for resistor tolerances. If you do that, I recommend putting a 0.1 uF ceramic capacitor from the 324 input to ground. Actually, I recommend it anyways.

Comment: ok, will definitely try that. thanks! would you recommend to use a precision voltage IC for my 2.5V reference for the AD620 instead of the voltage divider with follower that I am using now? because I am planning to use a 5V ref IC for my bridge excitation and also for an external analog ref for my arduino ADC

Comment: I'd say there's no need to use a separate reference, unless you don't trust your resistors not to change value. And if you don't trust them, you are hosed anyways.

Comment: actually i have a good news. I've bought the precision resistors earlier and tested it now and I am getting the exact difference value from my difference amp(AD822). Its only a few cents added compared to the 5% ones so I replaced all of my resistors with 1%. thanks for all your help! i'm just wondering why I always get an output on my AD620 a little less than my reference voltage though the book I have read and the simulation says that the Vout must be (V+ - (V-)) + Vref. So my output must be equal to Vref because the V+ and V- will be cancelled out since I am on zero load

Comment: Most bridge-type load cells have an intrinsic offset, which typically can be as much as +/- 5 % of full scale. Measure the AD620 input voltages when there is no load. Then short the AD620 inputs and measure the output.

Comment: I have measured 0.1mV at no load. with my gain at 381, that would be something like 38mV. I think that's the reason. thanks!